# Flattening one to many query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table called `Event` and this joins to one or more `Event Spaces`
within each Event Space is a booking start and end time.

These multiple event space lines are defined by an `event type` column which specifies whether the event space booking is the Check in, check out or the actual event.

Table structure looks like this

```
Event:
Event ID, Booking Start Date, Booking End Date

Event Space:
Event ID, SpaceCode, Event Type, Booking Start Time, Booking End Time
```

I want to bring those booking start times, and end times together on one row in my results. It's important to note that not all events will have multiple event spaces - some only have one.

**Desired output:**

```
Event ID, Bump in Start Time, Bump in End Time, Event Start Time, Event End Time, Bump out start time, bump out end time
```

When there is no result for one of the above columns it can either be left null or if someone has a better solution please let me know.

I have written a common table expression to pull this data together so far, but the resulting dataset is not flattened yet. I am having trouble coming up with a design to do so and would appreciate any ideas.

Thank you

**QUERY:**

```
    /*
    Bump in, bump out, event time
    grouped by DAY


*/
WITH Revenue as
(
SELECT  EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_ID as [Event], 
        Revenue = 
        SUM(Case
        When Orddtl.ER101_PHASE = '1' and ORDDTL.ER101_COMPL_STS = 'N'
        then ORDDTL.ER101_EXT_CHRG 
        When ORDDTL.ER101_PHASE = '5' and ORDDTL.ER101_COMPL_STS = 'N'
        then ORDDTL.ER101_EXT_CHRG 
        Else 0
        End),
        SM.EV800_SPACE_DESC,
        SM.EV800_SPACE_CODE

FROM    ungerboeck.dbo.EV200_EVENT_MASTER WITH (NOLOCK) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV870_ACCT_MASTER PrimCoord WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = PrimCoord.EV870_ORG_CODE 
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_COORD_1 = PrimCoord.EV870_ACCT_CODE -- Event manager
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV870_ACCT_MASTER FloorMgr WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = FloorMgr.EV870_ORG_CODE 
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_COORD_2 = FloorMgr.EV870_ACCT_CODE --  Floor manager
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV870_ACCT_MASTER EventAccount WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = EventAccount.EV870_ORG_CODE 
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_CUST_NBR = EventAccount.EV870_ACCT_CODE -- The person who made the booking 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV215_EVT_TYPE WITH (NOLOCK) -- get the event type
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = EV215_EVT_TYPE.EV215_ORG_CODE
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_TYPE = EV215_EVT_TYPE.EV215_EVT_TYPE 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV130_STATUS_MASTER WITH (NOLOCK) -- this might not be necessary. Only if we want to show status = completed, etc
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_STATUS = EV130_STATUS_MASTER.EV130_STATUS_CODE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV802_SPACE_BKD SPBK 
        ON SPBK.EV802_ORG_CODE = EV200_ORG_CODE AND SPBK.EV802_EVT_ID = EV200_EVT_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL ORDDTL
        ON ORDDTL.ER101_ORG_CODE = EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE 
        AND ORDDTL.ER101_EVT_ID = EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV800_SPACE_MASTER SM
        ON Sm.EV800_ORG_CODE = EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE
        AND SM.EV800_SPACE_CODE = SPBK.EV802_BKD_SPACE

WHERE   EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = '10' 
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_STATUS >= 30 /* only confirmed bookings */
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_STATUS <= 52 
        AND Not(EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_TYPE = 'GB') -- exclude group bookings

GROUP BY EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_ID,SM.EV800_SPACE_DESC,EV800_SPACE_CODE

), eventdetails as
(
SELECT  EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_ID as [Event], 
        EV215_EVT_TYP_DESC as [Event Type],
        EV200_event_master.EV200_EVT_DESC,
        EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_PLN_ATTEND,
        --EventAccount.EV870_NAME AS [Account], 
        PrimCoord.EV870_FIRST_NAME + ' ' + PrimCoord.EV870_LAST_NAME AS [Event Manager]
        --FloorMgr.EV870_FIRST_NAME + ' ' + FloorMgr.EV870_LAST_NAME AS [Floor Manager]

FROM    ungerboeck.dbo.EV200_EVENT_MASTER WITH (NOLOCK) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV870_ACCT_MASTER PrimCoord WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = PrimCoord.EV870_ORG_CODE 
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_COORD_1 = PrimCoord.EV870_ACCT_CODE -- Event manager
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV870_ACCT_MASTER FloorMgr WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = FloorMgr.EV870_ORG_CODE 
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_COORD_2 = FloorMgr.EV870_ACCT_CODE --  Floor manager
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV870_ACCT_MASTER EventAccount WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = EventAccount.EV870_ORG_CODE 
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_CUST_NBR = EventAccount.EV870_ACCT_CODE -- The person who made the booking 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV215_EVT_TYPE WITH (NOLOCK) -- get the event type
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = EV215_EVT_TYPE.EV215_ORG_CODE
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_TYPE = EV215_EVT_TYPE.EV215_EVT_TYPE 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV130_STATUS_MASTER WITH (NOLOCK) -- this might not be necessary. Only if we want to show status = completed, etc
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_STATUS = EV130_STATUS_MASTER.EV130_STATUS_CODE

WHERE   EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = '10' 
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_STATUS >= 30 /* only confirmed bookings */
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_STATUS <= 52 
        AND Not(EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_TYPE = 'GB') -- exclude group bookings


), spacedetails as
(
SELECT distinct 
SPDTL.EV803_BKD_SPACE,
SPDTL.EV803_EVT_ID,
SM.EV800_SPACE_DESC,
CONVERT(DATE,SPDTL.EV803_BKG_DATE) as bkg_date,
spdtl.EV803_START_TIME,
spdtl.EV803_END_TIME,
SPDTL.EV803_BKG_START_TIME,
SPDTL.EV803_BKG_END_TIME,
SPDTL.EV803_USAGE,
EV800_NOTE_1 AS [VENUE]
FROM ungerboeck.dbo.EV803_SPACE_BKD_DTL SPDTL
INNER JOIN ungerboeck.dbo.EV800_SPACE_MASTER SM ON SPDTL.EV803_BKD_SPACE = SM.EV800_SPACE_CODE

)

select eventdetails.Event,
[Event Type],
eventdetails.EV200_EVT_DESC as 'Description',
eventdetails.EV200_PLN_ATTEND as 'PAX',
eventdetails.[Event Manager],
spacedetails.EV800_SPACE_DESC as 'Space',
spacedetails.bkg_date as 'Booking Date',
spacedetails.VENUE,
/*
(CASE 
    WHEN spacedetails.EV803_USAGE = 'IN' THEN 'BUMP IN'
    WHEN spacedetails.EV803_USAGE = 'ET' THEN 'EVENT'
    WHEN spacedetails.EV803_USAGE = 'OUT' THEN 'BUMP OUT'
END) as 'Booking Type',
*/
(SELECT spacedetails.
CAST(spacedetails.EV803_BKG_START_TIME as time(0)) as 'Start Time',
CAST(spacedetails.EV803_BKG_END_TIME as time(0)) as 'End Time',
revenue.revenue


from eventdetails 
inner join spacedetails on eventdetails.Event = spacedetails.EV803_EVT_ID 
inner join Revenue on spacedetails.EV803_EVT_ID = revenue.Event and spacedetails.EV803_BKD_SPACE = Revenue.EV800_SPACE_CODE
```

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: @pcdev No, I am not trying to concatenate strings.These are separate columns

Comment: Your query doesn't match your purported table design.  Please either include the real table design, or a query that matches what you provided.

Comment: @STLDeveloper my table structure is a simplification of the underlying table. The real table has over 200 columns. Listing all of them does not seem practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question.

I used a subquery

```
 (
    SELECT TOP(1) s.EV803_START_TIME
    FROM spacedetails s
    WHERE s.EV803_EVT_ID = ss.EV803_EVT_ID
    AND s.EV803_USAGE = 'IN'
    AND s.EV803_BKD_SPACE = ss.EV803_BKD_SPACE
    AND s.bkg_date = ss.bkg_date
    ) AS 'Bump-in Start Time',
    (
    SELECT TOP(1) CAST(s.EV803_BKG_END_TIME AS time(0))
    FROM spacedetails s
    WHERE s.EV803_EVT_ID = ss.EV803_EVT_ID
    AND s.EV803_USAGE = 'IN'
    AND s.EV803_BKD_SPACE = ss.EV803_BKD_SPACE
    AND s.bkg_date = ss.bkg_date
    ) AS 'Bump-in End Time',


(
SELECT TOP(1) s.EV803_START_TIME
FROM spacedetails s
WHERE s.EV803_EVT_ID = ss.EV803_EVT_ID
AND s.EV803_USAGE = 'ET'
AND s.EV803_BKD_SPACE = ss.EV803_BKD_SPACE
AND s.bkg_date = ss.bkg_date
) AS 'Event Start Time',
(
SELECT TOP(1) CAST(s.EV803_BKG_END_TIME AS time(0))
FROM spacedetails s
WHERE s.EV803_EVT_ID = ss.EV803_EVT_ID
AND s.EV803_USAGE = 'ET'
AND s.EV803_BKD_SPACE = ss.EV803_BKD_SPACE
AND s.bkg_date = ss.bkg_date
) AS 'Event End Time',

(
SELECT TOP(1) s.EV803_START_TIME
FROM spacedetails s
WHERE s.EV803_EVT_ID = ss.EV803_EVT_ID
AND s.EV803_USAGE = 'OUT'
AND s.EV803_BKD_SPACE = ss.EV803_BKD_SPACE
AND s.bkg_date = ss.bkg_date
) AS 'Bump-out Start Time',
(
SELECT TOP(1) CAST(s.EV803_BKG_END_TIME AS time(0))
FROM spacedetails s
WHERE s.EV803_EVT_ID = ss.EV803_EVT_ID
AND s.EV803_USAGE = 'OUT'
AND s.EV803_BKD_SPACE = ss.EV803_BKD_SPACE
AND s.bkg_date = ss.bkg_date
) AS 'Bump-out End Time',
```

Comment: You might want to add some `order by` clauses in there, or you may get unexpected output, depending on what your data looks like.  Alternatively you could use `max` or `min` with `group by`.